# Combine single and multi argument variables in a function call for Python

Tags: python, python-3.4, argument-passing

I wrote the following function to return a subset of a dictionary but want to insist on having at least one key provided in the input arguments.

```
def getProperty(self,x, *key):
    key = [k for k in key]
    key.insert(0,x)
    return {k:self.__properties[k] for k in key if k in self.__properties}
```

The code works.

I know the insert is not really necessary since dictionary elements aren't ordered.  What I really wish I could do is to get rid of the first for-loop that creates a list by extracting elements from the multi-argument tuple.

Something like

```
key = [x] + [key]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by `it does not work`?

Comment: `since dictionary elements aren't ordered` - where is the dictionary?

Comment: key is already a list/tuple, and x may be added directly in dict

Comment: The dictionary is __properties.  I just wanted to retrieve a subset of it given input keys, where at least one is mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
def getProperty(self,x, *key):
    key = (x,)+key
    return {k:self.__properties[k] for k in key if k in self.__properties}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this is exactly what I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insist on there being at least one argument then you should [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=assert#grammar-token-assert_stmt) that the `args` tuple is not empty

```
>>> def get_property(*args):
...     assert (args != ()), "There must be at least one argument"
...     print(args)
...
>>> get_property('a')
('a',)
>>> get_property('a', 'b')
('a', 'b')
>>> get_property()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in get_property
AssertionError: There must be at least one argument
>>>
```

There's no need, then, to do anything fancy to provide one separate argument when you call the method and you can catch the `AssertionError` in the calling statement if required.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I was looking more for code optimization solutions, but did not think of doing this either.